# Hall-effect sensor PWM jitter from switching converter

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, pwm, lipo, linear-regulator, hall-effect

I am designing a circuit to power two magnetic sensors using a Li-po battery (nominal voltage = 3.7 V), DC-DC boost converter, and then either an LDO linear regulator or a buck converter to generate a low-noise output of 5 V to power the sensors (I am using [this Hall-effect sensor](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/drv5057.pdf?ts=1707771530426&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fmanufacture.alldatasheetcn.com%252Fview.jsp%253FSearchword%253DDRV5057)).

I am curious if the noise level input to these particular sensors has an influence on the jitter of the output PWM waveforms, and on that token, if using a buck regulator to power the 5 V line (given it has inherent voltage/current fluctuations during a switching event) is a suboptimal choice due to its ability to thereby increase PWM jitter.

I am new to using these sensors so wanted to ask for clarity. I would like to use a non-switching converter best-case scenario due to the low noise, but the problem is the efficiency of non-switching regulators tends to be a lot lower and I have limited power.

Comment: Have you used an oscilloscope to probe upstream for the earliest signs of noise? If signal impedance is high it will be very sensitive to noise. I would bite the bullet and use the very quiet linear supplies, but that's just my take on it.

Answer (score 4):

The internal diagram shows a band-gap reference so it should not be too bad, but there's really no solid information to go on. The internal voltages are very small so high frequency noise on the supply could have an effect. You could test for it.. however..

If you take adequate precautions to deal with mismatches, in this case just returning the pullup to the MCU power rail, there is nothing stopping you from using a switching regulator for other stuff and another regulator - this one an LDO - just to power the Hall sensor. Or just add an RC or other filter to the Hall sensor power.